# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException - Does not an array initialized to default values by itself? (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I have an array of objects of type, let's say, Object.

```
Object[] array = new Object[M];
```

As far as I know, when you specify the length of the array to be M (where M some number), it is created an array with M default values for this type of array. For example, if I had an array int[], there would be M zeroes. Now that I have an array with objects, I expect to have M null objects, from index 0 up to index M-1.

However, when I assign for the first time a value at index M-1:

```
array[M-1] = obj;
```

I get a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: M

Obviously I misunderstand something, but I don't know what it is ... Could you help me figure that out?

EDIT: I put my comment below, might help.

Assume that I have an array of ints, e.g.

```
int[] array = new int[3];
```

When this statement runs, I think - please correct me if I am wrong - that if I will print my array I will get [0, 0, 0], i.e. I will have zeroes (the standard value for int[] arrays) at indexes 0, 1, and 2 (since I defined a length 3).

Now if I try to do for example:

```
array[2] = 5
```

I should get [0, 0, 5] and not an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException since the index already exists upon allocation - it is a fixed array, not a dynamic one that starts from size zero and grows up to capacity (or even more)!

That's exactly what I did in my code - only difference, I have objects instead of ints. Therefore, IF what I say is right, then somewhere else is the problem in my code and I should post it in another question.

EDIT 2: Please check [Cache Implemented Using an Array - ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22029459/cache-implemented-using-an-array-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-java)

Comment: Is this all the code? Can you show us the declaration and use of `M` and other relevant code.

Comment: Sorry, when I do that I don't get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, assuming M is a number > 0.

Comment: What was the actual number in the `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` message?  Is it consistent with what you expect?

Comment: @JesusRamos    Yes, sure, I just thought my logic is all wrong and therefore no more code needed. I will edit my question with more code.

Comment: Is this the same `M`?  Is this a variable whose value might have changed?

Comment: @rgettman      Yes, it is I think. I wanted to test my code, so I putted M = 4 and I tried to add the first object at index M-1 = 3. The M in the exception message was 4.

Comment: @ajb           No, M is a fixed number. I give it a value - M=4 in the test I did in my code. It does not matter the actual value, just thought of it as a fixed number.

Comment: @PeterHiggs: *"...so I putted M = 4 and I tried to add the first object at index M-1 = 3. The M in the exception message was 4"* Then you weren't using `M-1`. Fundamentally, though: Create an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). You'll either figure it out doing so, or we'll be able to help you with it.

Comment: *"Does not an array initialized to default values by itself? (Java)"* Yes, it does. The default value for each of the entries in your array is `null` (because the array is of type `Object[]`). The default values of the entries don't relate to `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22029459/cache-implemented-using-an-array-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-java

Answer (score 3):

The problem is if x is outside the boundaries of 0..M-1.

For example, let´s suppose you try to assign array[x-1] when x = 0.

Then you´ll get this ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: I am not sure if I got it. Let's try with a simple example. Assume that I have an array of ints, e.g. int[] array = new int[3];. When this statement runs, I think - please correct me if I am wrong - that if I will print my array I will get [0, 0, 0], i.e. I have zeroes (the standard value for int[] arrays) at indexes 0, 1, and 2 (since I defined a length 3). Now if I try to do array[2] = 5 (a number) I should get [0,0,5] and not an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException since the index already exists upon allocation - it is a fixed array, not a dynamic one that starts from  0 and grows!

Comment: @PeterHiggs you're absolutely right. All values 0, 1 and 2 in the example you've wrote must work. But you must double check your code. Do you want to share it with us? (sometimes, we stare so much time looking for a problem that we simply can't find it)

Comment: Yes, of course. I will share in another post and edit the link at this post.

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22029459/cache-implemented-using-an-array-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-java

Comment: hi @PeterHiggs thanks for sharing your code. I've left an answer there, I hope it helps.